# buildozer download android sdk without api

Tags: android, buildozer

I run `buildozer android debug` and I see this:

```
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/hamid/Desktop/myfirstkivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /home/hamid/Desktop/myfirstkivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are ()
[WARNING]: Requested API target 19 is not available, install it with the SDK android tool.
[WARNING]: Exiting.
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/hamid/Desktop/myfirstkivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
```

As you can see , there is no android API.
And when I tried to install an API using android sdk manager at `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/android` there where no API to install it :
[image: there is no api]

How I can install API for android SDK? Can I download SDK or API manually and connect it to buildozer? Why buildozer can not download correct SDK?